# running cpp programs in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

I started to write cpp programs using the emacs editor in windows.

I would like to know what other softwares I need to have in order to be able to run these programs completely inside emacs. I need to know something like where to find the common h files included in cpp programs and where to put them.

I am lost in googling, and need advice from programmers. Before, I worked on CodeBlocks, but now I want to switch to emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Emacs, you can execute a shell INTO a frame. You have just to split up your screen, with C-x 2 or C-x 3 and type M-x shell to start the shell... And there, you can call gcc to build your app (or your Makefile), and execute him (./a.out)

Comment: Actually, for compilation, it's better to use `M-x compile`, as that will allow you to walk between errors (not that I do that, I tend to compile in a separate shell, and use `M-g` (in XEmacs, in regular emacs it's `M-g-g`) to go to the line with the error.

Comment: @ScrolaWebDev thanks this is really a good solution that worked, although I want to be able to use M-x compile of emacs, but I will clarify my question in another Q.

Answer (score 3):

Use "M-x shell" to start a shell, and type ./a.out (or whatever your program is called). Requires no extras if you are on a linux machine.